# haskell -skipping getLine

Tags: haskell, getline

hey - great coders and haskellers,
i'm a haskell freshman and have a problem with a program
it boils down to the following situaition

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "\nplease give me some input"
    input1 <- getLine
    putStrLn "\nplease give me another input"
    input2 <-getLine
    putStrLn ("\nyour inputs were "++show(input1)++" and "++ show(input2)")
    putStrLn "restart ?? yY or nN"
    c <- getChar
    restart c
    where 
    restart c
        |elem c "yY" = do
            main
        |elem c "nN" = putStrLn "\nExample Over"
        |otherwise = do
            putStrLn "\nyou must type one of Yy to confirm or nN to abort"
            c'<- getChar
            restart c'
```

on any but the first execution of main

```
input1 <- getLine
```

is skipped and i can find no reason for it, as the following

```
input2 <- getLine
```

is executed as expected, i'm open for any suggestions and help
thanks in advance ε/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix: set `NoBuffering` at the start of your program:

```
hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
```

Why does this fix the issue?  Look at what you're typing when you don't using NoBuffering!  You type, and `getLine` consumes:

```
first input[enter]
```

Then you type, and `getLine` #2 consumes:

```
second input[enter]
```

Then you type:

```
 y[enter]
```

But `getChar` only consumed the `y` and leaves the `[enter]` buffered, which your first `getLine` call reads!  Why did you type `[enter]`?  Because you had to, just hitting 'y' didn't cause `main` to loop because the terminal was line buffered.

Comment: thankt this helped a lot, do i have to import the whole System.IO for this or can i import parts only too
yours ε/2

Comment: All you need is `import System.IO (hSetBuffering, stdin, BufferMode(NoBuffering))`

Comment: ahh thx i tried to import NoBuffering intstead of BufferMode(NoBuffering) thx ε/2