# 'getLine' not working as intended, being skipped

Tags: haskell

I am fairly new to Haskell and am writing some simple text/file manipulation functions. I am currently attempting to modify a string before adding it to a file.

I have a function 'insertChar' which adds a character at any given position in a string (using the solution of problem 21 from 99 problems in Haskell https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/21_to_28).

```
import System.Environment   
import System.Directory  
import System.IO 
import Data.List  

main :: IO ()
main = do 
      putStrLn "Insert a string"
      word <- getLine
      putStrLn "Insert a char"
      char <- getChar
      putStrLn "Insert a position"
      pos <- getLine *line which is skipped*
      let x = (read pos :: Int) *converts string into int*
      putStrLn "Adding char to list..."
      let newS = [(insertChar char word x)] *result of insertChar is set to 
      newS*
      putStrLn "Printed list: "
      print (newS) *print new string*
      putStrLn "Insert file name"
      file <- getLine
      putStrLn "Adding new string to file..."
      add file newS

insertChar :: a -> [a] -> Int -> [a]
insertChar x ys     1 = x:ys
insertChar x (y:ys) n = y:insertChar x ys (n-1)

add :: String -> [String] -> IO ()  
add fileName [item] = appendFile fileName item
```

The user is asked to enter a string, then a character they wish to add to this string and finally the position in the string where they wish to add the character. I can input the string fine but when I press enter after inputting the character, the 'getLine' for inputting the position is skipped and the following error is produced;

```
GHCI>main
Insert a string
hello world
Insert a char
s
Insert a position
Adding char to list...
Printed list:
["*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

I have seen this stack overflow post; [haskell -skipping getLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605983/haskell-skipping-getline)

and have attempted to follow that answer changing the code to;

```
import System.Environment   
import System.Directory   
import System.IO (hSetBuffering, stdin, BufferMode(NoBuffering)) *New line*
import Data.List  

main :: IO ()
main = do 
      hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering *New line*
      putStrLn "Insert a string"
      word <- getLine
      putStrLn "Insert a char"
      char <- getChar
      putStrLn "Insert a position"
      pos <- getLine 
      let x = (read pos :: Int) 
      putStrLn "Adding char to list..."
      let newS = [(insertChar char word x)] 
      putStrLn "Printed list: "
      print (newS)
      putStrLn "Insert file name"
      file <- getLine
      putStrLn "Adding new string to file..."
      add file newS

insertChar :: a -> [a] -> Int -> [a]
insertChar x ys     1 = x:ys
insertChar x (y:ys) n = y:insertChar x ys (n-1)

add :: String -> [String] -> IO ()  
add fileName [item] = appendFile fileName item
```

However, it still produces the same error. Any clue what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Since you use `getChar` the cursor is simply placed after that character. You probably want to add a `getLine` before the one you marked to put the cursor to the next line first.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard I have removed the image and included output in text format

Comment: @user10731678 Thanks. :) I removed downvote.

Comment: You linked to a question that has the exact same root cause as yours, but didn't actually apply the recommended fix from the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Willem Van Onsem's comment on my original question I have been able to find a solution. I added a "getLine" after the line 'putStrLn "Insert a position"' so the code now looks like;

```
import System.Environment   
import System.Directory  
import System.IO 
import Data.List  

main :: IO ()
main = do 
      putStrLn "Insert a string"
      word <- getLine
      putStrLn "Insert a char"
      char <- getChar
      putStrLn "Insert a position"
      temp <- getLine *line that has been added*
      pos <- getLine
      let x = (read pos :: Int)
      putStrLn "Adding char to list..."
      let newS = [(insertChar char word x)]
      putStrLn "Printed list: "
      print (newS)
      putStrLn "Insert file name"
      file <- getLine
      putStrLn "Adding new string to file..."
      add file newS

insertChar :: a -> [a] -> Int -> [a]
insertChar x ys     1 = x:ys
insertChar x (y:ys) n = y:insertChar x ys (n-1)

add :: String -> [String] -> IO ()  
add fileName [item] = appendFile fileName item
```

Comment: @MichaelLitchard I will!

Answer (score 0):

You imported the right stuff, but never actually called it! Try this:

```
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
    -- ...all the rest of your original main, exactly as it used to be
```

This way, when it gets to the `getChar` line, it will return from the `getChar` as soon as you press a key -- not wait until you press enter. The UI will make more sense, and the code will, too, because you don't need to swallow a phantom newline that the user didn't actually want to enter anyway.

Comment: As stated in the question this did not work for me. I have also tried to put it in my main function like you suggest here but it instead closes GHCI completely

Comment: @user10731678 Wow! Now *that* is worth a fresh question, if it can be reliably reproduced. Include the code that closes ghci, and the exact things you do to load/run the code.

Comment: I cannot seem to replicate GHCI closing (not really sure why?), however removing the 'temp -> getLine' and placing 'hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering' in my main function and importing it at the top creates the original problem

Comment: @Seb I can't reproduce. After deleting your comments, adding the `hSetBuffering` line, and calling `runhaskell test.hs`, when I type `foo` followed by an enter, then `i` (followed by no enter!) it immediately proceeds to ask me for a position; entering `3` followed by enter causes it to print `["foio"]`. The same happens if I substitute typing `main` (and pressing enter) in `ghci test.hs` instead of using `runhaskell`. Can you describe in similar detail the sequence of actions you're taking and the behavior it displays?

Comment: I have edited my question above to show what I have been doing using 'hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering'. I am Running it through GHCI by first loading it and then running the 'main' function, ':l TextEditor.hs' followed by 'main' (as seen in the error section of the question). It still skips the line where the user can input a position

Comment: @Seb Can you please describe in detail what input actions you take once `main` starts? In particular, I suspect that you are mistakenly pressing "enter" after entering a character at the "Insert a char" prompt.

Comment: I am indeed pressing "enter" after entering a character. I am confused on how else I am meant to trigger the rest of the program without pressing enter? I press enter after main. I then input my string and press enter. I input my character and press enter, the error occurs

Comment: @Seb Enter after `main`, good. Input your string and press enter, good. Then press a character, and do not press enter. The program will proceed to prompt you with "Insert a position" instantly, and you can then enter your position and press enter.

Comment: This is all very bizarre. It simply does not carry on unless I press enter. Main -> enter -> insert a string -> abc -> enter -> insert a char -> d -> nothing unless I press enter and then the error is produced.

Comment: @Seb Huh. Okay, this question definitely isn't a dupe; though I can't reproduce that behavior here. What version of GHC are you using? Are you super-duper sure that you've saved the file and are loading the file you saved to (I know that sounds dumb, but... I've seen it before...)?

Comment: Version is 8.6.3, yes just double checked. Everything saved and loaded correctly. I understand it may not be best practice but I am going to mark the solution above as correct. It looks odd from a code perspective but from a UI point of view it works